# missing plesk-mysql-server.x86_64

Tags: mysql, plesk

While updating mysql on centos6.9 I accidentally removed `plesk-mysql-server.x86_64` and now I cant run `PLESK`.  How can I re-install this?
This was my original output from `yum list installed | grep -i mysql`

> ```
> mysql.x86_64                        5.1.73-8.el6_8                     @base
> mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64         5.1.5r1144-7.el6                   installed
> mysql-libs.x86_64                   5.1.73-8.el6_8                     @base
> mysql-server.x86_64                 5.1.73-8.el6_8                     @base
> perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64               4.013-3.el6                        installed
> php56w-mysql.x86_64                 5.6.30-1.w6                        @webtatic
> plesk-mysql-server.x86_64           12.5.30-cos6.build1205150826.19    installed
> ```

Now I get

> ```
> compat-mysql51.x86_64              5.1.73-1.el6.remi                   @remi
> mysql.x86_64                       5.5.56-1.el6.remi                   @remi
> mysql-libs.x86_64                  5.5.56-1.el6.remi                   @remi
> mysql-server.x86_64                5.5.56-1.el6.remi                   @remi
> perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64              4.013-3.el6                         @base
> php56w-mysql.x86_64                5.6.30-1.w6                         @webtatic
> ```

Comment: Contact Plesk support for assistance. This is even more off-topic here than ServerFault where you originally posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download and install package http://autoinstall.plesk.com/PSA_12.5.30/dist-rpm-CentOS-6-x86_64/contrib/plesk-mysql-server-12.5.30-cos6.build1205150826.19.x86_64.rpm